# Vala basics Goo & GTK+

Tags: gtk3, vala

I'm trying to write my first Vala application and I'm desperatly in need for a
jumpstart as I have some VAPI conflict.

The app is bare minimum (like you would expect):

```
public class RoxyApplication : Gtk.Application {

  public RoxyApplication () {
    Object (application_id: "roxytesting",
            flags: ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE);
  }

  protected override void activate () {
    Gtk.ApplicationWindow window = new Gtk.ApplicationWindow (this);
    window.set_default_size (800, 600);
    window.title = "Roxy App 0.0.1";

    Goo.Canvas canvas = new Goo.Canvas ();
    window.add (canvas);

    Gtk.Label label =  new Gtk.Label ("Roxxy moxxy");
    window.add (label);
    window.show_all();
  }

  public static int main (string[] args) {
    RoxyApplication roxapp = new RoxyApplication ();
    return roxapp.run (args);
  }
}
```

when I'm compiling with:

```
valac-0.40 -o main --pkg goocanvas --pkg GTK+-3.0 main.vala
or 
valac-0.40 -o main --pkg goocanvas main.vala
```

respectively I get:
3115 errors all in sense of

```
"gtk+-2.0.vapi:8397.2-8397.42: error: `Gtk' already contains a definition for `tree_get_row_drag_data'
```

and 2 errors:

```
main.vala:1.32-1.46: error: The type name `Gtk.Application' could not be found
public class RoxyApplication : Gtk.Application {
```

Is it even possible to use these libraries together?
Als far as I can get a grasp Goo is extension of GTK+
and not a subset. (or is it still?)

Thanks in advance for your pointers.

Comment: Have you tried goocanvas-3.0? You need a version of GooCanvas that is compatible with Gtk+ 3.0.